# Can i skip a whole file (malloc.c etc) using GDB?

Tags: c, linux, gdb

Using GDB we can set breakpoints and step into the test program. Sometimes on continuing step by step we step into some library file like "malloc.c", which we might not be really interested in looking into the whole file.

Can it be possible to skip the whole file? Like is there are command like: `skip malloc.c` like that? If not, how to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no such command, but you can use `finish`, which jumps to the end of a function. It will speed up things a little.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than `step`, why not use `next` to go to the next line without stepping into the function call?

Comment: you can also use `finish` to run to the end of the current function if you step into a function you don't care about

Comment: @Chris Dodd. Thanks it was useful. Can you please write it as an answer, so that i can accept it :)? But is something like malloc.c there? I guess no. One file, can have plenty of functions that we may want to skip :)

Answer (score 3):

Since GDB 7.4 you can use `skip file /path/to/malloc.c`.